# Is $\sec^2 x - \tan^2 x$ a constant function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

If $f(x)=\sec^2 x$, $g(x) = \tan^2 x$ then $$p(x)=f(x)-g(x)=1,$$ which is a constant function but its graph is discontinous at $$(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$$ even though $1$ is not discontinuous.

So, if given a function like $p(x)=1$ can we rewrite it as $-x+x+1$, or even $\sec^2(x) - \tan^2(x)$?

Or does $\sec^2(x) - \tan^2(x)$ have a domain which does not contain odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If we simplify resulting function so that the domain of individual functions are excluded but we get a graph discontinous at points where their domain is not defined

Comment: Putting it roughly but I hope helpfully: at any odd multiple of $\frac\pi2$, the "value" of $f(x)-g(x)$ is $\langle\hbox{undefined}\rangle-\langle\hbox{undefined}\rangle$, which is **not** $0$ or $1$ or anything, it is undefined.

Comment: $p:=\sec^2-\tan^2$ is not the function $1$  defined on $\Bbb R$ because the domain of $p$ is not $\Bbb R$ but  $\Bbb R$ minus the odd multiples of $\pi/2.$

Comment: Since the function is continuously (even smoothly) extendable to $\mathbb{R}$, you could identify it to its extension and say it's equal to $1$ to be fair, but if you want to be correct, as well as perform operations like summing, multiplying, composing with other functions, or differentiating the expression of the function then you have to be aware of its actual, original domain.

Comment: Note that your function (though only defined on a subset of $\Bbb R$) is constant and as such, continuous (which you seem to doubt).

Answer (score 7):

To define a function, we have to specify the domain.

In our case, $$p: \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{(2n+1)\frac\pi2: n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\} \to \mathbb{R}, p(x)=\sec^2(x) - \tan^2(x)$$ is not the same as
$$q: \mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}, q(x)=1$$

since they do not share the same domain.

However, it is equal to

$$r: \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{(2n+1)\frac\pi2: n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\} \to \mathbb{R}, r(x)=1$$

which is a constant function on the domain.

Answer (score 1):

The expression sec²x - tan²x is not a constant function, as it depends on the value of x. However, it can be simplified using trigonometric identities to yield a constant function.

Using the identities sec²x = 1/cos²x and tan²x = sin²x/cos²x, we can write:

sec²x - tan²x = 1/cos²x - sin²x/cos²x = (1 - sin²x)/cos²x

We can further simplify this using the identity cos²x + sin²x = 1:

sec²x - tan²x = (cos²x/cos²x)/cos²x = 1/cos²x
At this point, we should note that the function 1/cos²x is not defined for x = (2n+1)π/2, where n is any integer, since cos(x) = 0 at these points.

Therefore, we can define a function p(x) given by:

p(x) = sec²x - tan²x, x ∈ { x ∈ R | x ≠ (2n+1)π/2, where n is any integer }

On this domain, p(x) is equivalent to the constant function q(x) = 1/cos²x, since p(x) simplifies to q(x) for all x in the domain of p(x).

So, on the domain specified, we can say that sec²x - tan²x is equivalent to the constant function q(x) = 1.

Comment: "The expression sec²x - tan²x is not a constant function, as it depends on the value of x" sound weird. Actually, it *is* a constant function (on its domain of course: it cannot mean anything else). And in the final sentence, the phrase "is *equivalent* to" is clumsy as well. The meaningful wording would be that the former is a *restriction* of the latter. But that sentence is anyway useless. Any restriction of a constant function is ipso facto a constant function.